# English equivalent of joie de vivre

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an English equivalent of the French **joie de vivre**,
a feeling of pleasure and excitement that comes from enjoying life?

I know that the French phrase can be used in English, but I'm looking for an apt English word/short phrase.

Comment: you could try ***lust for life***

Comment: *Joie de vivre* **is** English. OTOH, if we had an English equivalent, why would we borrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is a well-established one in English and is present in all main dictionaries. It is part of the English language as many others loanwords. There is no equivalent expression that would carry the same strong connotation:

***[Joie de vivre](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/joie-de-vivre)***

> a feeling of great happiness and enjoyment of life.

(Cambridge Dictionary)